# Flutter filter firebase database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "story" : {
    "-MTOpnFnINch-hCT4tG7" : {
      "creatorId" : "KEieXFzt9zezgP9684EhCxRNzp42",
      "img" : "https://www.petyourdog.com/uploads/breed_lists/Toy-Dog-Breeds.jpg",
      "story" : "111111111111333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333222222222",
      "title" : "111111111111111111"
    },
    "-MTOq-_X96CLJ6-v6WFx" : {
      "creatorId" : "EJW4BU1IRMUtchW1bzUPmeLzttZ2",
      "img" : "https://naturaldogcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/shutterstock_194843813-web-180x180.jpg",
      "story" : "qqqqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwqwwwwww",
      "title" : "qqqqqqqq"
    },
    "-MTP0N2MkCj44I7aPudf" : {
      "creatorId" : "KEieXFzt9zezgP9684EhCxRNzp42",
      "img" : "https://naturaldogcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/shutterstock_194843813-web-180x180.jpg",
      "story" : "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk",
      "title" : "yyyyykkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
    },
    "-MTUgGBHkcnOBCMmToGU" : {
      "creatorId" : "KEieXFzt9zezgP9684EhCxRNzp42",
      "img" : " ",
      "story" : "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "title" : "ooooooooooooo"
    }
  },
  "userFavorites" : {
    "KEieXFzt9zezgP9684EhCxRNzp42" : {
      "-MTOq-_X96CLJ6-v6WFx" : true
    }
  }
}
```

This is the data I'm working on. Im trying to filter the data on the user story page, where only the user own data are shown.

Here the code:

```
  class Stories with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Story> _storys = [
    
  ];

  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  Stories(this.authToken, this.userId, this._storys);



  List<Story> get storys {

    return [..._storys];
  }

  List<Story> get favoriteItems {
    return _storys.where((storyItem) => storyItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Story findById(String id) {
    return _storys.firstWhere((story) => story.id == id);

  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
    final filterString = filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"' : '';
    var url =
        'https://unified-adviser--#####..firebaseio.com/story.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url =
          'https://unified-adviser-#####.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
      final List<Story> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Story(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          story: prodData['story'],
          // price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite:
              favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
          img: prodData['img'],
        ));
      });
      _storys = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
.
.
.
.
```

the user story page, where I'm trying to filter the data

```
class UserStory extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'userStory';
  
  Future<void> _refreshProducts(BuildContext context) async {
    await Provider.of<Stories>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetProducts(true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('rebuilding...');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Your Products'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EditStoryScreen.routeName);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _refreshProducts(context),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) =>
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () => _refreshProducts(context),
                    child: Consumer<Stories>(
                      builder: (ctx, productsData, _) => Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: productsData.storys.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                                    children: [
                                      UserStoryItem(
                                        productsData.storys[i].id,
                                        productsData.storys[i].title,
                                        productsData.storys[i].img,
                                      ),
                                      Divider(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the method that Im using is not working, even when I do sign up with a new account I can view all the data in the UserStory page and edit or delete them!

What is the problem here?

Comment: It looks like you are using some sort of Firebase function to access Realtime database. You need to check this function that you are calling and understand what is going on. Look also in functions log to see if there is errors. For me the filter string also looks strange because  &equalTo="$userId"' did not say what field of database should be equal to userId, it looks like it should be creatorId...

Comment: It is quite hard to say what's going wrong with the amount of code you shared. Can you print `url` and tell us what value it shows?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done. And to be more spicific which var do you want to print? I'm going to look into the extractedData in the fetchAndSetProducts

Comment: The value of `url` as it is set after this line `var url =
        'https://unified-adviser--#####..firebaseio.com/story.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  the result of that was the whole data like the page before it. I was using didChangeDependencies on both pages and for some reason that was the issue. I solved it by using two function to fetch the data! Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: If you solved the problem, can you write the solution (with the code yuo changed) up as an answer? That way it may be useful to someone who in the future finds themselves in the same situation as you.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the filter string is wrong. You can use the following. However, if it doesn't work, you might want to use the [Firebase RTDB](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview) package.

```
final filterString = filterByUser ? 'orderBy=\"creatorId\"&equalTo=\"$userId\"' : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

See what i used for mine

```
final filterString = filterByUser ? {'auth': '$authToken', 'orderBy': '"creatorId"', 'equalTo': '"$userId"' } : {'auth': '$authToken'};
    var url = Uri.https(
      'https://unified-adviser--#####..firebaseio.com',
      '/story.json',
      filterString,
    );
```

Comment: remove https:// in your link

Answer (score 0):

> you can compare your code with this

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
try {
  final Map<String, dynamic> queryParametersAuth = {
    'auth': '$authToken',
  };
  final Map<String, dynamic> queryParametersAuthWithFilterByUserId = {
    'auth': '$authToken', 
    'orderBy': '"creatorId"',
    'equalTo': '"$userId"',
  };
  //final filterString = filterByUser ? 
  //{'auth': '$authToken', 'orderBy': '"creatorId"', 'equalTo': '"$userId"' } : {'auth': '$authToken'};
  final queryParametersFilterString = filterByUser
      ? queryParametersAuthWithFilterByUserId
      : queryParametersAuth;
  var url = Uri.https('shop-in-89a45-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
      'products.json', queryParametersFilterString);      
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(response);
  print(json.decode(response.body));      
  final extractedFetchProduct =          
      json.decode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>; 
  if (extractedFetchProduct == null) {
    return;
  }

  url = Uri.https('shop-in-89a45-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
      'userFavorites/$userId.json', queryParametersAuth);
  final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
  final favoriteResponseBody = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
  final List<Product> listLoadedProduct = [];
  extractedFetchProduct.forEach((keyProductId, valueProductItem) {
    listLoadedProduct.add(Product(
      id: keyProductId,         
      title: valueProductItem['title'],         
      description: valueProductItem['description'],          
      price: double.parse(valueProductItem['price'].toString()),      
      imageUrl: valueProductItem['imageUrl'],          
      isFavorite: favoriteResponseBody == null
          ? false
          : favoriteResponseBody[keyProductId] ??
              false,
    ));
  });
  listProduct = listLoadedProduct;
  notifyListeners();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

}

Comment: i really don't need credits i just share my code with you & credit goes to the top Answer no 1st in the list that answer helped me with the same filter in url error. now it's good